# How export objects to the given location in Liquibase

Tags: oracle, liquibase, sqlcl

I have already installed Liquibase Version: 4.21.1 and SQLcl Version: 23.1.0.089.0929 and set the 'Path' in environmental variables like

```
C:\Program Files\liquibase 
D:\sqlcl\bin
```

Also, it allows me to export objects like

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2965]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\sqlcl\bin>sql username/Password@localhost:1521/xe


    SQLcl: Release 23.1 Production on Thu May 18 12:35:52 2023
    
    Copyright (c) 1982, 2023, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
    
    Last Successful login time: Thu May 18 2023 12:35:53 +09:30
    
    Connected to:
    Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
    Version 21.3.0.0.0
    
    SQL>
    SQL> lb generate-apex-object  -applicationid 100 -split
```

However, I need to export objects into given folder path instead of 'D:\sqlcl\bin' folder. Can anybody help me how to achieve this?

Comment: This is not really about programming question and probably a good fit on an other SE site for DB management

Answer (score 0):

SQLcl writes the changeLog and it's changeSets to whatever the current working directory is.

The 'pwd' command will show what your working directory is, for both reading and writing files.

```
SQL> pwd
c:\sqlcl\23.1\sqlcl\bin\
SQL>
```

Obviously, you don't want to write your source code/project work to the application bin directory, so what you'll do instead is use the CD command.

```
SQL> pwd
c:\sqlcl\23.1\sqlcl\bin\
SQL> cd c:\users\jdsmith\desktop
SQL> lb generate-object -object-name regions -object-type table
--Starting Liquibase at 08:47:17 (version 4.17.0 #0 built at 2022-11-02 21:48+0000)

Changelog created and written out to file regions_table.xml

Operation completed successfully.

SQL> !dir *.xml
 Volume in drive C is System
 Volume Serial Number is F897-6A6F

 Directory of C:\Users\JDSMITH\Desktop

05/19/2023  08:47 AM             3,718 regions_table.xml
               2 File(s)          5,522 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  91,137,302,528 bytes free

SQL>
```

This applies for doing things like using the LOAD and SPOOL commands. And of course, you can put this into your scripts so it's always going to use the files/directories you want it to.